# File picker cannot pick audios

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Unable to pick audios from my device with the file_picker package. I'm able to pick all other types of files like images, videos and documents. But audios are the only problem.

Here's a video sample

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOI1d.gif)

As you can see from the sample, videos, images and documents are displayed but not audios. And there are audios files present on my device.

This is my code

```
import 'dart:developer'; 

  

 import 'package:cloud_vault/utils/navigations.dart'; 

 import 'package:cloud_vault/views/screens/file_upload.dart'; 

 import 'package:cloud_vault/views/widgets/file_type.dart' as k; 

 import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart'; 

 import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

 import '../../utils/textstyle.dart';

class FileTypesModalSheet extends StatefulWidget { 

   const FileTypesModalSheet({super.key}); 

  

   @override 

   State<FileTypesModalSheet> createState() => _FileTypesModalSheetState(); 

 } 

  

 class _FileTypesModalSheetState extends State<FileTypesModalSheet> { 

   FilePicker filePicker = FilePicker.platform; 

  

   Future<void> pickFile(FileType fileType) async { 

     FilePickerResult? result = await filePicker.pickFiles( 

       type: fileType, 

       allowMultiple: true, 

       allowedExtensions: 

           fileType == FileType.custom ? ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'] : null, 

     ); 

  

     if (result != null) { 

       // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously 

       navigateTo( 

           context, 

           FileUpload( 

             pickedFile: result, 

             fileType: fileType, 

           )); 

     } 

   } 

  

   @override 

   Widget build(BuildContext context) { 

     return Column( 

       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, 

       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 

       children: [ 

         Text( 

           "Select a file type to upload", 

           style: kTextStyle(context: context, size: 15), 

         ), 

         Row( 

           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, 

           children: [ 

             k.FileType( 

               iconData: Icons.image, 

               title: "Image", 

               onTap: () => pickFile(FileType.image), 

             ), 

             k.FileType( 

               iconData: Icons.video_collection_outlined, 

               title: "Video", 

               onTap: () => pickFile(FileType.video), 

             ), 

           ], 

         ), 

         Row( 

           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, 

           children: [ 

             k.FileType( 

               iconData: Icons.audio_file_outlined, 

               title: "Audio", 

               onTap: () => pickFile(FileType.audio), 

             ), 

             k.FileType( 

               iconData: Icons.file_copy_outlined, 

               title: "Document", 

               onTap: () => pickFile(FileType.custom), 

             ) 

           ], 

         ), 

       ], 

     ); 

   } 

 }
```

Comment: You need to add allowed extension in mp3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

To pick an audio file, simply use a custom file type:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['mp3', 'aac', 'wav'],
    );
```